# EmberJS 2.10 How to properly set nested route controller to set actions on the route?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm a little confused with the controller asigned to a route.

I want to create an action called "showModal" on the route but when I use this code ember sends an error that the action is not defined on the route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({


actions: {
    showModal: function (params) {
        console.info(params);
        if (params) {
            Custombox.open({
                target: '.mModal',
                closer: false
            });
        } else {
            Custombox.close();
        }
    }
  }
});
```

However, if I use the next code all seems to work fine, the modal action can be called by any component:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        this._super(...arguments);
        controller.set('actions', this.actions);
    },
    actions: {
        showModal: function (params) {
            console.info(params);
            if (params) {
                Custombox.open({
                    target: '.mModal',
                    closer: false
                });
            } else {
                Custombox.close();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I would like to know, how can I assign a controller to a route? so the actions will be correctly defined on the route.

By the way I use the next ember-cli command to create my route: ember g route new/quote

Update 1:

Added hbs code

```
<div class=row>
      {{form-employee-search modal=(action "showModal")}}
 </div>
```

Comment: If you're using closure actions they can't be defined on routes only on controllers.

Comment: Te idea is that the component do an action and then calls the route action the second code does the functionality

Comment: Can you paste your template where you're calling component?

Comment: Yes, your action is defined as closure action which is good, only problem is that they need to be defined in controllers, or use helper from answer I posted then you can define them in routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably defining your action in template as a closure action(using (action 'actionName') syntax). Closure actions can't be defined on routes they need to be defined on controllers. You can create controller and define action there or use ember-route-action-helper that enables you to define closure actions on routes.
https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper

Regarding you question how to assign controller to a route, you just need to create controller with the same path as your route. From the [guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/controllers/)

> The value of my-controller-name must match the name of the Route that renders it. So a Route named blog-post would have a matching Controller named blog-post.
>
> You only need to generate a Controller if you want to customize its properties or provide any actions. If you have no customizations, Ember will provide a Controller instance for you at run time.

Comment: How can I create the controller and assign it to the route?

Comment: Use ember g controller and provide same path as for your route
- ember g controller new/quote

Comment: Ok let me try that and I'll tell you if that work, but I'm pretty sure that I had already try that and does not work.

Comment: Create controller, move actions hash from route to controller, delete setupController and it should work.

Comment: Sorry a power failure on the building as soon as I can try your solution I'll let you know

Comment: Yes that works I move all the actions to the controller